# Creating quiz questions using Spotify API

Tags: python, api, spotipy

Currently I'm working on a quiz game for a project which uses the spotify API. Our approach is to get get the data from the api and use it to make multiple choice questions about one specific artist. Right now we are stuck at the part where we connected to the api and have the raw data but can't turn it into (randomly generated) questions?
How should we start or approach it? Is there a way to code that or we want to make something that is not possible?

So far I haven't had any useful solution idea or find answers, similar quiz games usually use python dictionaries for storing questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Spotify Developer Policy: ["Do not create a game, including trivia quizzes."](https://developer.spotify.com/policy/#:~:text=Do%20not%20create%20a%20game%2C%20including%20trivia%20quizzes.)